# How to turn off "Requires Full Screen" option in iOS using Cordova 6?

Tags: ios, cordova

When you create an application using Cordova 6, then build it for iOS, you will see that if you open the project properties on XCode, the option "Requires full screen" is enabled:

[image: Requires full screen option is checked on iOS]

This is very troublesome because it prevents the app from "multitasking" on iOS (you cannot split the screen with your app open), as mentioned in [[CB-9161] Support iPad multitasking in iOS 9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9161):

> Just want to mention, the fix (2) also needs to update the project's
>   info plist file to indicate the app does not require the full screen
>   as shown below
>
> ```
> <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
> <false/>
> ```

In previous versions of Cordova, you were able to control this option using the [`FullScreen`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference) preference. However this no longer has an effect on iOS. The recommended alternative way is to use the [cordova-plugin-statusbar](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/) plugin. But this does not provide any option to turn off full screen and the other options offered by the plugin do not allow multitasking either.

Question: how do you turn off the "Requires full screen" option from your Cordova 6 project (meaning: without having to manually update the XCode project after building for iOS)?

Comment: I would like to add our app was recently rejected because it was full screen and the "pull to reveal the status bar" feature was not implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [Cordova Custom Config plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)

With that plugin, you can pretty much change anything on the `plist` or `manifest`file via the `config.xml`

So in your case, after installing the plugin, just add:

```
 <config-file parent="UIRequiresFullScreen" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <false/>
 </config-file>
```

in your `config.xml`

Comment: I could not get the cordova-custom-config plugin install properly using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova. So I used the [cordova-plugin-settings-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-settings-hook) plugin instead, which achieved the same results.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tested it, but we might no longer need to install a plugin to achieve that. Cordova has added native support for "config-file": https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file

Comment: Apple will reject your app if you set that flag to false, starting with iOS 11. I suppose that is due to the iPhone X.

Comment: You mean, Apple will reject the app if you DONT require full screen?

Comment: I got an app rejected because I submitted it with "Requires Ful Screen" unchecked. Go figure.